# Add Usercontrol as ListBoxItem from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm very new to MVVM (and WPF). I have a main view that has a ListBox with the same usercontrol added to it x times.No problem adding these controls. The UC conatins a ListBox that will hold an unknown number of items. Can these items be another UC ? How do I not break MVVM and add items to the ListBox of each UC added?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the usercontrol in a Datatemplate in the ItemTemplate of the listbox. refer the below sample.

```
<Window x:Class="MSDN15Jan2015_Learning.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MSDN15Jan2015_Learning"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ListBoxItemControl/> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
 class MainViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> perList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList 
    {
        get { return perList; }
        set { perList = value; }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        perList.Add(new Person() { Age = 1, Name = "Test1"});
        perList.Add(new Person() { Age = 2, Name = "Test2" });
        perList.Add(new Person() { Age = 3, Name = "Test3" });
        perList.Add(new Person() { Age = 4, Name = "Test4" });
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
<UserControl x:Class="MSDN15Jan2015_Learning.ListBoxItemControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was driving me wacko.

Comment: Are you getting this answer.. Do u need any explaination?

Comment: All set - Works fine.